# Can't transition from UIScrollView to UIPanGesture in one movement

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, parallax, uipangesturerecognizer

What I want to achieve: http://youtu.be/SUWxVtpc0JA

What I can achieve: http://youtu.be/b1xH6Xsvxcg

I’m trying to do the same vertical parallax scrolling effect that the Year Walk Companion app does when you change from text page to menu.

I’ve been able to do this effect on `UIScrollViews` that only move horizontally, by using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to move up and down, (imagine swiping between nested arrays). However when I have a `UIScrollView` with the vertical scrolling it breaks.

When I scroll down the `UIScrollView` it moves as you would expect, same if you move up. However the issues start when I want the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to come in and move the `UIScrollView` itself vertically, not it’s content. To do this so far I have subclassed `UIScrollView` to make a test on the function `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` :

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer* pan = (UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer;
    CGPoint panGestureTranslation = [pan translationInView:self];
    if (self.contentOffset.y == 0 && panGestureTranslation.y > 0 ) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

It returns `NO` when my `UIScrollView` is at the top, and allows my other UIPanGesture for the parallax scrolling between pages to start again.

My problem is, when my `UIScrollView` is scrolling and reached the top, the function `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` will not be called and force me to release the touch before allowing the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to parallax scroll.

The question: How can I stop the handle of the touch by the `UIScrollView` and let the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` get the touch going up without release my finger from the screen?  (like in the Year Walk Companion app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` isn't called because a new touch 'session' hasn't started. The existing one is still in progress and the gesture said it didn't want to start.

You could create your own gesture subclass which stays possible and only starts when the content offset < 0. Or you could use the scroll view delegate methods as your input and not use gestures at all.